# Read long text with voice on using TextToSpeech

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am implementing text reading with voice on [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android).

The code works, but I find the difficulty that `TextToSpeech` can not read more than 4000 characters at a time.

**How can I make my method read me all the text when it exceeds the limit allowed by `TextToSpeech`?**

It seems the best way is to create a mechanism that separates the text in several parts and read it in a kind of queue of readings. I tried to read the different parts by calling inside a loop `tts.speak (partText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, bundle, null)` but only reads the first occurrence of the loop.

I have been researching and on several sites talk about using `QUEUE_ADD` and `onUtterance`, but I can not figure out how to implement or create that read queue.

Here is my code:

### Method invoked when clicking on the reading icon:

```
public void ttsFunction() {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    Locale locSpanish = new Locale("spa", "ESP");
                    int result = tts.setLanguage(locSpanish);
                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                            || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lenguaje no soportado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.v(TAG, "onInit exitoso");
                        final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_oficio);

                        String strTexto = mTextView.getText().toString();
                        leerTexto(strTexto);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Falló la inicialización", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

### Voice reading method

```
void leerTexto(String strTexto){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Log.v(TAG, "API 21+");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        strTexto = strTexto.substring(0,3999); //Así funciona
        tts.speak(strTexto, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, bundle, null);
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "API 15-");
        HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
        param.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        tts.speak(strTexto, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, param);
    }
}
```

Comment: Split it into multiple inputs,

Comment: @war_Hero no problem with that, my problem is how read these multiple inputs using tts.